# ZF3 Same Controller name and Alias in Multi Module

Tags: module, controller, zend-framework3

Hello i have a Zf3 project.

I have multi module with same controller name and alias

my goal

```
localhost/cart/index
localhost/user/index
```

but

```
localhost/user/index
```

always go to module cart indexController
how to solve this problem

1.module cart

```
'controllers' => [
    Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class],
    'aliases'=>[
        'index' => Controller\IndexController::class ,
    ],
],

'router' => [
    'routes' => [
    'cart' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/cart[/:controller[/:action]]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

2.module user

```
'controllers' => [
    Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class],
    'aliases'=>[
        'index' => Controller\IndexController::class ,
    ],
],

'router' => [
    'routes' => [
    'user' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/user[/:controller[/:action]]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: my bad, its working now. look like some typo in my code. thanks

Comment: Could you either: 1 - create an answer showing the problem and its solution or 2 - remove the question?  - The only issue I see in the code is a missing `factories` key parent for the Controller => Factory combination